# Setting the maximum length of a edittext in android

Tags: java, android

I want to restrict the length of an edittext to 11 characters.I have tried the following and it doesnt work:

in xml:  `android:maxLength="11"`

in java code:

```
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(11);
        txtifsccode.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

In newer kitkat version when the length crossed 11 characters the text disappeared and started fresh in the edittext.How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Are you supposed to use __android:maxLength__ with __InputFilter.LengthFilter__ ?

Comment: I tried separately but still didnt work.

Comment: Are you facing this on a certain, possibly faulty, device? Or do you refer to any device/emulator running 4.4.x?

Comment: I tried in android 2.6 as well as 4.4.2 device.The issue is there for both.But in the 4.4.2 device the text vanishes after 11 characters.

Comment: remove the java code, the xml only should work. If you put a java code for the same function it overrides xml

Comment: @Elgert no i tried it it doenst work with the xml alone too.

Comment: Could you please insetr the full exittext xml code with the container layout? I think the problem occurs in the layout parameters you set. It could occur, when you set android:ellipsize or also if you set android_layout_width="wrap content" and there is another view after the edittext.